# Function in python from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, types, type-conversion, data-conversion

I need help for writing this JavaScript function in Python.

- Write a javascript function that accepts a string as a parameter and converts the first letter of each word of the string in upper case. e.g 'the quick brown fox'

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:** `'The Quick Brown Fox'`

What I wrote so far:

```
function upperCase (str) {
  var array1 = str.split(' ');
  var newArray1 = [ ];

  for (var x = 0; x < array1.length; x++) {
        newArray1.push (array1[x].charAt(0).toUpperCase 
        ()+array1 [x].slice (1));
  }
   return newArray1.join (' ');
}
console.log (uppercase ("the quick brown fox"));
```

Comment: 'the quick brown fox'.title()

Comment: When you run your function in javascript, you get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: uppercase is not defined`. When you use the correct function name, it works exactly as expected

Comment: Now I don't understand the convert to python part. Are you running it in python using the `pyv8` interpreter? Or do you want to re-write it in python?

Comment: @-Fred Stark .....rewrite it in python.